# How can I find what command a keybinding is bound too easily?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode:
I would like to press a combination of keys and see what command it is bound too, like "C-h k" in Emacs.

Comment: Open the keyboard shortcuts (from the gear icon) and you can search for "CTRL X X" or whatever to see what is bound to those keys/  As well as ALT/Shift/etc.

Comment: Quite reasonable, thanks!

Comment: Although it would of course be more intuitive to just be able to press the combination instead of having to type it out. Will post a feature request for this.

Comment: For the record: Tobias filed [Issue 38602](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/38602).