# VSCode does not allow me to type the colon (:)

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode does not reconize when I try to type a colon. It works outside of VSCode (i.e. Google) just not in the editor.

Solutions that I have tried

1. Uninstalling VSCode and re-installing
2. New Keyboard
3. Disabling and Uninstalling all extensions
4. Ensured my keyboard is set to US

Nothing works. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to use the keyboard troubleshooter to see what is happening. Read this answer I wrote yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47304223/how-can-i-find-what-command-a-keybinding-is-bound-too-easily/72180187#72180187

Comment: If you can't figure out the problem from reading the troubleshooters output when you press the colon key, then please include the lines (and only the lines) that print when you press **':'**