# Bind key to closing autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, visual-studio-code, key-bindings, cancellation

When I look at the actions bound to "Escape" on Visual Studio Code, there are a lot of them used to quit out of something.

I'd just like the functionality of being able to hit "ctrl" to cancel the autocomplete function.

Which one of these commands should I use? (I have tried "hideSuggestWidget" and "list.clear", neither of them work.)

(As seems to be the theme with these sorts of questions, in Atom, I'd just use the key-binding-resolver, but Visual Studio Code doesn't seem to [have that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38911486/does-visual-studio-code-have-a-key-binding-resolver#38935403) [yet](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/19280092-add-a-keybinding-resolver-that-shows-which-shortcu).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+q",
    "command": "hideSuggestWidget",
    "when": "suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "escape",
    "command": "-hideSuggestWidget",
    "when": "suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
  }
```

but you see I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> because just binding to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button would do nothing.  It seems you cannot bind a command to only the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button.

So, the `"hideSuggestWidget"` appears to be the right one with associated `"when"` clauses.  I would be interested to know if it is possible to bind only to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button.